# Windows Boot Manager not detected

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu along with windows 10 in UEFI mode,when I boot into Ubuntu with USB,start the installation,it doesn't shows the option:
"Install Ubuntu alongside windows boot manager".

I tried last time doing with the option "Something else",but messed up the EFI partitions because of which my Windows got corrupted as well.

Please provide some suggestions how to make that option appear in the installation?

Comment: Almost always, turn off fast start up in Windows. Also best to have fast boot off in UEFI. But if Windows corrupted, you need a Windows repair disk to repair it first. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I have turned off fast boot,secure boot and have re-installed windows,still it doesn't show that option

Comment: should I install it with acpi=off?

Comment: Only some brands may need that boot parameter. What brand/model system. And that would only help booting, not seeing partitions. Does live installer work ok in live mode? Does gparted then show partitions?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I realized what I did wrong,somehow,I installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode and windows was in UEFI mode,I have seen many answers for this,isn't there a software which would bring Ubuntu to UEFI mode as well

Comment: Also when I change the boot mode to UEFI,boot into Ubuntu with USB,write this line: [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
     in terminal,it displays BIOS,please suggest some way with which I can install it in UEFI mode.